# transversal intersection of three curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, intersection-theory, transversality

Let me start by saying this is my first post. I am new to intersection theory and am currently reading *Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology* and have a question on the intersection of $3$ curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Let us say we have $3$ curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for example, the $ x$, $y$, and $z$-axis. I think they satisfy the transversal intersection property because their tangents span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but intuitively it doesn't seem to be a stable intersection (I could just slightly move one of the curves away from the others and the intersection would be removed). Is this specific example an example of a transversal intersection in $\mathbb{R}^3$? I would also like to orient this intersection and would like some input on that. Would something similar to the scalar triple product be of use to me?

Anything that can help me resolve this or any references that I should read further to help clear this up is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^3$ by R3?

Comment: yes sorry I do not know how to use the math text

Comment: Just a guess: check the definition. Perhaps the transversality stability  depends on what happens when you jiggle the _directions_ (the tangent vectors), keeping the point of intersection.

Comment: Your situation is described in the textbook on page 30. You may want to read that.

Comment: I think you can learn math typing by MathType software for $1$ month free(Trial version) and then maybe you could learn it your own :)

Comment: on page 30 it describes the intersection of 2 coordinate axes intersecting in R2 being transversal but 2 coordinate axes in R3 not being transversal. My question is does adding the 3rd coordinate axis then make the intersection transversal. The book only describes the intersection of 2 submanifolds not 3. I do not know if things change once you intersect 3 submanifolds

Comment: For future posts, [you can find information on using MathJax here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). A useful trick not mentioned there is that if you right-click on a formula and select "Show Math As >> TeX Commands", you can see how to create it.

Comment: Your question could be improved if you would include the definition of transversal that you are using, and if you could explain to us what happened when you attempted to apply that definition to the situation of your question.

Comment: Right, emphasizing @LeeMosher's point, what definition are you inventing for transversality of more than two submanifolds?